# Am I less likely to encounter cross-browser issues if I use php instead of server-side javascript to build a website?

Tags: php, javascript

Recently, I've been involved in two projects.

The first one is built on php and the second in Javascript (using http://nodejs.org/).
Well, I thought that since php depends mostly on the hosting provider, if the site works in one browser it should work in all the rest. Since Javasscript depends mostly on the browser I should encounter more issues in different browsers.

What about the Javascript part that handle the things between the client and server side?

Am I right? Or I'm not considering something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server Side javascript does not runs in browser. So it wont have cross browser issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **server-side** Javascript, it doesn't matter what browser the **client** is using. From the browser's perspective, there could just as well be a team of well-trained monkeys keying HTTP responses into a teletype somewhere -- all that matters to them is that you're returning data. It doesn't matter to the client what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Browser issues are in essence completely independent of PHP, period. After all, at the end of the day when the script finishes then all you get is HTML output.